# SQL Query join with more than one table with relation one-to-many

Tags: mysql, join, optimization

I have following tables:

**tbl_destination**

```
id_destination INT PRIMARY
destination_name VARCHAR(200)
```

**tbl_destination_category**

```
id_destination_category INT PRIMARY
id_destination INT
id_category INT
```

**tbl_destination_activity**

```
id_destination_activity INT PRIMARY
id_destination INT
id_activity INT
```

**tbl_category**

```
id_category INT PRIMARY
category_name VARCHAR(200)
```

**tbl_activity**

```
id_activity INT PRIMARY
activity_name VARCHAR(200)
```

I want to select destination data, with category and activity WHERE:

- One destination can have many category (tbl_destination one-to-many tbl_destination_category)
- One destination can have many activity (tbl_destination one-to-many tbl_destination_activity)

My expected output example:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Destination name                       
Category 
                                 
Activity
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mount Everest
                      
Mountain, nature
                      
Hiking, Trekking, Camping

Is this possible to do in one single query? or whats the most efficient query?

Answer (score 0):

you would have more than one row per relationships, but your SQL is here:

```
 select td.destination_name,  tc.category_name, ta.activity_name
 from tbl_destination td
 inner join tbl_destination_category tdc on tdc.id_destination = td.id_destination 
    iiner join tbl_destination_activity tda on tda.id_destination = td.id_destination 
    iiner join tbl_category tc on tc.id_category = tdc.id_category 
    inner join tbl_activity ta on ta.id_activity  = tda.id_activity
```

Comment: Use group by and group_concat to get output as OP asked for.